# Why does javascript global variable use causing large allocations?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

In the code below, I use the variable diff to store the difference between the goal location of a particle and the actual. When I store that value into a local "var diff" my memory allocations do not grow. If I use a global "var diff" declared outside of the function or with the declaration omitted entirely I see huge memory allocations. Why would using a global variable cause huge allocations?

I've left the working, non  code commented.

On a side note the particle variable below when made global does not change the amount of allocations. In both cases the code performs the task required.

Tested on Chrome Version 30.0.1599.101 m

Code:

```
//Could also declare global for diff or particle out here with no change.
LoadingScreen.prototype.Update = function(delta)
{
    var size =  this.totalParticles - 1;
    while(size--)
    {
        //Works perfectly
        var particle = this.particleSystem.geometry.vertices[size];
        //Also works perfectly with no extra allocations.
        /* particle = this.particleSystem.geometry.vertices[size]; */
        if(size >= this.row)
        {
            //Works perfectly
            var diff = particle.gridy - particle.y;
            //Causes huge memory allocations garbage collection and the like
            /* diff = particle.gridy - particle.y; */
            if(diff < 5 * delta)
                particle.y = particle.gridy;
            else
                if(particle.y != particle.gridy)
                    particle.y += 500 * delta;
        }
    }
    this.row = this.totalParticles * (loadStatus.left / loadStatus.total);
    ...
};
```

Comment: Can you give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: `while(size--) //infinite loop?`

Comment: Even though there is memory allocation (as seen in a task manager), that doesn't mean the memory is valid. It could just be residual that the garbage collector hasn't seen the need to free up yet. Alternatively, if you're using `diff` elsewhere in the code beyond the `Update` method, it could be a memory leak~

Comment: Why *would* you want to use a global variable there at all? Chances are good that you're simply confusing the garbage collector. Btw, what browser (version) did you test this in?

Comment: Why are you not iterating over the last particle? Remove that `- 1` after `this.totalParticles`.

Comment: @Markasoftware—only if *size* is initially -1.

Comment: @RobG: or if (for some reason) it's not an integer.

Comment: @Bergi Version 30.0.1599.101, I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @zamnuts diff is used only in this section. The memory gets allocated with every pass of the function and when the statement is changed from global to local it continues to have problems.